# Postgres ignoring index on join, but all planner estimates are correct?

Tags: postgresql

I've got a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES ('abc123')) AS user_ids(user_id)
) AS user_ids(user_id)
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = user_id
```

But instead of using the index on `users.id`, the query planner opts for a `seq scan` on the ~2.5M row `users` table:

```
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Hash Right Join  (cost=0.03..400966.32 rows=1 width=1065)
   Hash Cond: ((users.id)::text = ('abc123'::text))
   ->  Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..391452.66 rows=2536966 width=1033) <-- HERE
   ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
         ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=32)
```

Notice that the estimates (ie, on the size of the users table, and that exactly one row will be returned) are correct.

Also, Postgres will use the index on `users.id` (a unique primary key index) for other queries:

```
=> EXPLAIN SELECT *
-> FROM users
-> WHERE id IN ('abc123');
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.56..8.57 rows=1 width=1033)
   Index Cond: ((id)::citext = 'abc123'::citext)
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the string literals in the subquery / `VALUES` statement are of type `text`, while the `users.id` column is of type `citext`, and the `citext` index can't be used when comparing `citext = text`.

When the input type is `citext` the index is used:

```
=> explain select * from users where hash = 'abc123'::citext;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.56..8.57 rows=1 width=1033)
   Index Cond: ((hash)::citext = 'abc123'::citext)
(2 rows)
```

But the index isn't used when the input type is `text`:

```
=> explain select * from users where hash = 'abc123'::text;
                          QUERY PLAN                          
--------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..397795.08 rows=1 width=1033)
   Filter: ((hash)::text = 'abc123'::text)
(2 rows)
```